# using unsafe c#dll in c++/cli,one method of the c#dll has a parameter void**

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a MFC project with clr option to mix C++ and C++/CLI. And I also have a unsafe C# dll (only a C# dll, I only know the return value and the parameter of the method) which has a method `void OpenCamera(Model model, void** camera)`

when use this dll in C# project (unsafe), it can be easily used like this:

```
void* tmpCamera;

a->OpenCamera(model, &tmpCamera);
```

I am a newer of C++/CLI, so I wrote (c++/cli):

```
A^ a=gcnew A(); // build a object of Class A of the C# dll

void* tmpCamera; // maybe wrong, there is no void* in c++cli  

a->OpenCamera(model, &tmpCamera); // compiles OK. But cannot run OpenCamera method
```

throw a exception in the dll,but cannot know what exception

another way:

```
pin_ptr<void> tmpCamera; // I think it can run

a->OpenCamera(model, (void**)&tmpCamera); // compiles OK. But also cannot run
```

throw a exception in the dll,but cannot know what exception

How to pass a `void**` in c++/cli to the c# method? Both pin_ptr and interior_ptr cannot run the method with `void**` parameter.

Comment: Pretty unclear, you really do need to find out what the exception is trying to say.  Look in the Output window.  A C# method would use `out IntPtr` for that argument.

Comment: Your first code should work, just try initializing `tmpCamera` to `nullptr` before the call.

Answer (score 0):

void** is pointer to pointer.So, you declare it as "void ** name".I think this should work.

Comment: void* tmpCamera + &tmpCamera is the same as void**,isn`t it?